# misunderstanding of web API source code

Tags: javascript, web, speech-recognition, upgrade

I want to build a web speech recognition and I met with some difficulties with the source code that I took it from google developers web site

```
 `if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
  upgrade();
  } else {
  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.interimResults = true;     
recognition.onstart = function() { ... }
recognition.onresult = function(event) { ... }
recognition.onerror = function(event) { ... }
recognition.onend = function() { ... }
...`
```

So my problem I want to know about *upgrade()*:
1- what does it mean?
2- what it's role exactly?

thanks for your your answers :) ...

Comment: Since [the goal of writing a blog post is to provide useful information to others with a minimum of noise and clutter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115694/why-is-saying-thank-you-in-question-undesirable), remove your signature/thanks/will-be-appreciated. That being said, Welcome on SO.

Comment: I assume it's to give the user feedback if webkitSpeechRecognition does not exist.  aka.  None webkit browsers..